# How to make an element of an array bold in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I am using fpdf
I want to make an element of an array look bold.

```
$cell3[8][0] = 'Improved Yield : Farmer Business School Training';
```

After Assigning all those values I will print them in pdf document

```
$pdf->FancyTable_2c($head3,$cell3);
$pdf->Cell(8,5,'',0,1);
```

How to do this?

Comment: do you want people code for you? Try something, post it, you'll get better feedback

Answer (score 7):

You need to set the font you want, then add the cell and then change the style back:

```
//declare a style
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"This will be regular Arial");

//declare another style, overwrites previous one
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"This will be Arial Bold");

//set it back to normal
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 10);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"This will be regular Arial once more")
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SetFont`](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setfont.htm). The `style` parameter is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi matt, I am trying to display in the pdf, the text bold for one element in cell(array). Not for all elements, only for one element i want to make it bold. It is kind of sub heading.